# Detecting whether a coordinate falls within a predefined area in Android google maps

Tags: android

I am writing an app that has functionality to select GPS markers based off of their location. How is it possible to test whether a GPS coordinate falls within a given area? I already have the area data, available in GeoJSON, KML, and Shapefile. However, after browsing the api, I cannot find any method that tells me how to test if a point is within an area.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any code sample that you can share?

Comment: No. I am asking whether there exists any method that is able to detect whether a GPS coordinate falls within a certain area.